# Critical exponent in Sobolev scale and singular continuous measure

Tags: measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

Recently I started the following [discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406959/what-is-the-critical-exponent-for-irregular-function-in-the-sobolev-scale) about Sobolev spaces where I was interested in finding the maximal $s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that given function/distribution belongs to the Sobolev space $H^s$. Continuing this topic I'm interested in knowing what is the optimal exponent $s_0$ for the following distribution: let $F$ be the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) (called sometimes the Devil's staircase). There is a measure $\mu$ on the real line with the function $F$ as CDF. This measure is somewhere inbetween discrete and absolutely continuous (with respect to the Lebesgue) measure.

> What is the supremum of the set of all $s$ such tht $\mu \in H^s$? Call this supremum $s_0$: is it true that $\mu \in H^{s_0}$?

EDIT 1: Maybe it is worthwhile to add that, provided one knows the Fourier coefficients, there is a simple criterion for belonging to $H^{s}$: so maybe the better way to state my question would be:

> What are the Fourier coefficients of $\mu$?

EDIT 2: After reading the paper indicated in the comment below I understood that it is possible to give an explicit formula for Fourier coefficients: $c_n=(-1)^n \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \cos({\frac{2\pi n}{3^j}})$. By taking $n=3^q$ one obtains nonzero constant subsequence of $(c_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which shows that the sequence of Fourier coefficients does not tend to $0$: however I find it not so easy to find the optimal $s_0$ since the formula for $c_n$ involves an infinite product which seems to be hard to control. So to summarize, my question boils down to the following problem:

> For which values $s>0$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|c_n|^2}{n^{2s}}$ is convergent (where $c_n$ are as above)?

Comment: See: Remarks on a Known Example of a Monotone Continuous Function, by E. Hille and J. D. Tamarkin
https://doi.org/10.2307/2298506

Comment: Since the distributional derivative of devils staircase is a Radon measure, the devils staircase is in $BV[0,1]$ the space of functions of bounded total variation on $[0,1]$. This space is slightly larger than $W^{1,1}$, but (if I am not mistaken) is contained in $W^{\alpha,1}$ for every $\alpha<1$. If I remember Sobolev embeddings correct, this should imply that the devils staircase is in $H^s$ for $s<1/2$ (but not for $s=1/2$).

Comment: Ok, after reading Leoni's "A first course in Sobolev space" I see that there is some subtle issue: The Cantor function does not have a weak derivative (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41311/how-to-prove-that-the-cantor-ternary-function-is-not-weakly-differentiable)), hence, it is not even a Sobolev function. Hence, the Sobolev scale is not the right place to look at. If you define Sobolev spaces via Fourier series, then things may be different. I think what I wrote above is correct then, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @Dirk by saying that the devil staircase is not weakly differentiable probably you meant that its (possible) weak derivative should be an element in $L^1$. This is however impossible. But still it's derivative is well defined distribution (which cannot be represented by a function) and this derivative is exactly $\mu$ described in my question. Since the sequence $(c_n)_n$ is bounded it follows that $\mu \in H^s$ for $s<\frac{1}{2}$ and since $(c_n)_n$ contains a constant subsequence it follows that $\mu$ does not belong to $H^0$ which is $L^2$ (and this is expected)...

Comment: Therefore an optimal $s$ is somewhere between $-\frac12$ and $0$. Note that this constant subsequence is very scarce $n=3^q$ so the corresponding series where we sum up only over $n=3^q$ would be convergent if $s<0$